# How to recognize a context free grammar with a rust declarative macro

Tags: rust, macros, context-free-grammar

While I was implementing a regex tool in Rust, I tried to create a fancy macro to write regex:

```rust
regex!['a' 'b'? ('c' | 'd')*] // ab?(c|d)*
```

But only by using the `macro_rules`, no procedural macro. I figured out that a stack is necessary as this is a context-free grammar, not a regular grammar. I managed to get the following language recognized:

```
expr
  = '1'
  | '*' expr
  | '+' expr expr
```

The stack just stores `.` to know how much expressions have to be ignored

```rust
macro_rules! parse {
    // empty stack, parse the expression
    ([] 1 $($t:tt)*) => { val() };
    ([] * $($t:tt)*) => { uni(parse!([] $($t)*)) };
    ([] + $($t:tt)*) => { bin(parse!([] $($t)*), parse!([.] $($t)*)) };
    // not empty stack, ignore the first expression
    ([. $($o:tt)*] 1 $($t:tt)*) => { parse!([$($o)*] $($t)*) };
    ([. $($o:tt)*] * $($t:tt)*) => { parse!([. $($o)*] $($t)*) };
    ([. $($o:tt)*] + $($t:tt)*) => { parse!([. . $($o)*] $($t)*) };
}
macro_rules! expr {
    ($($t:tt)*) => { parse!([] $($t)*) };
}
```

```rust
let e = expr!(+ *1 1);
let e = bin(uni(val()), val());
```

The macro suffers from a high complexity, it parses the same expression multiple time, a little bit like a recursive Fibonacci.

At this point, it would be better to produce an array of token and to use a proper parser to produce the desired tree. But this is for the art and to push the limit of `macro_rules`. Please, see it as a pure curiosity thing.

Is it possible to recognize infix operators?

Is it possible to handle precedence?

Is it possible to recognize the "follow" operator (when two expressions are side by side `1 1`) ?

Is it possible to avoid parsing more than once the same expression?

Can we take advantage of different stack elements than just a `.` ?

Comment: Relevant: https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/tt-muncher.html